# Using Abstract Data Types with Kotlin, Spring Boot and Thymeleaf templates

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, thymeleaf, abstract-data-type

I'm learning how to use Kotlin with Spring Boot, but I really want to use Kotlin's ADTs in the Thymeleaf template. My ADT looks like:

```kotlin
sealed class CheckAvailabilityData {
    data class Available(val name: String)
    data class Unavailable(val age: Int)
}
```

So, the question is how can I use the object in IntelliJ, to do a if block, so depending of the concrete type of the value, I want to render some diferent HTML. Something like:

```html
<div th:if="${availability is Available}">
The avalaible name is ${availability.name}
</div>
<div th:if="${availability is Unavailable}">
Unavalable for age ${availability.age}
</div>
```

So, the questions are:

- is some best practice to use Kotlin's ADT in a Thymeleaf template?
- is there some template engine better to use ADT's?
- what level of support offers IntelliJ *and* Thymeleaf to this use case? or is it not a good way to do that?